# How are method(obj) calls handled in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Now, as far as I can tell, calling `obj.method` or `method(obj)` seems to give the same results. However, when I tried to see how `subsref` behaves in these cases, I came to the startling realization that `method(obj)` doesn't seem to go through the subsref mechanism. So how are these calls then handled and is there a practical way to override them?

I'm trying to do this, so I can make something like `method(object).otherMethod` possible (which I would obviously be handling through a custom `subsref`). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`method(obj)` effectively just calls the function `method` on `obj`. `obj.method` goes through `subsref`, which then farms it out to the same function, unless you've implemented your own custom `subsref`. I'm not sure what you mean by 'overriding' `method(obj)` - you can't make the MATLAB dispatch process work differently.

Rather than `method(obj).otherMethod`, you would typically do `tmp = method(obj); tmp.otherMethod`.

If you try to fully reimplement `subsref` to the degree of handling arbitrarily deeply nested and complex expressions - which could take the form, for example, of `obj.property{1}.structfield(2).method.otherMethod` - things get very complex very fast. I would typically try to handle only a small depth of nesting, and then pass anything deeper off to `builtin('subsref')`.